# raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I need to scan an image using `pytesseract` and then translate the text into English. Everything works fine, but then all of a sudden I start getting this 429 error out of nowhere. I'm confused about how it worked 10 minutes prior to that.

I searched for a solution and inserted the `time.sleep()` function, which kind of worked, but when I tried to run it again, it gave me the same error. This problem arose due to the translation, as far as I can tell.

I tried to isolate the `goslate` module and wrote a separate program just translating the text file into English, but it still gave me the same error.

```py
import goslate
import time


with open('final1.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    gs = goslate.Goslate()
    translatedText = gs.translate(data,'eng')

with open('tran.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(translatedText)
    time.sleep(5)
```

The expected result is that I should be able to see the translated text in the `tran.txt` file, but instead this is the error I'm getting:

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

The above was just the last few lines of the error. Also, I can't seem to find how exactly I should use the `requests` module so I can try that out too.

Comment: `goslate` seems to be sort-of not liked by google; see the note on top of the [package website](https://pythonhosted.org/goslate/). Maybe that's the reason why your requests get refused?

Comment: okay. can you suggest any alternative modules where I can easily translate my text?

Comment: idk, maybe look into `textblob`. nlp is not really my field of expertise I must admit so just ask google for more ;-)

Comment: `textblob` is actually the same. `goslate` is better anyway for bulk translations.

Comment: There is googletrans.